# Django star rating system AJAX and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-views

I am trying to implement a star rating system on a Django site.

I have found the following, and like the style of the stars here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_star_rating.asp

Currently have a limited understanding of JavaScript, AJAX and Django. Does anyone know how to use the stars in the above example combined with AJAX and Django, so you are able to update the database (models) without a page refresh when a user selects a rating?

It is also important that users are only able to vote once, i.e. they are not allowed to rate a page twice. For this, there must be an IP check. I am confused about the code and I need help.

`models.py`:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='ratings', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0, 
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(5), 
            MinValueValidator(0),
        ]
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

`views.py`:

```
def RatingView(request):
    obj = Rating.objects.filter(score=0).order_by("?").first()
    context ={
        'object': obj
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context)

# def get_client_ip(self, request):
#       x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
#       if x_forwarded_for:
#           ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
#       else:
#           ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
#       return ip

def RateView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        element_id = int(request.POST.get('element_id'))
        val = request.POST.get('val')
        print(val)
        obj = Rating.objects.get(id=element_id)
        obj.score = val
        obj.save()
        return JsonResponse({'success':'true', 'score': val}, safe=False)
    return JsonResponse({'success':'false'})
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('rate/', views.RateView, name='rate'),
    path('<slug:slug>/<slug:post_slug>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.CategoryView.as_view(), name='category'),
    path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

`html`:

```
<div class="col text-center">
    <form class="rate-form" action="" method="POST" id="{{ object.id }}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star my-btn" id="first"></button>
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star my-btn" id="second"></button>
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star my-btn" id="third"></button>
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star my-btn" id="fourth"></button>
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star my-btn" id="fifth"></button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="confirm-box"></div>
</div>
```

`JavaScript`:

```
// Stars
const one = document.getElementById('first')
const two = document.getElementById('second')
const three = document.getElementById('third')
const four = document.getElementById('fourth')
const five = document.getElementById('fifth')

const form = document.querySelector('.rate-form')
const confirmBox = document.getElementById('confirm-box')
const csrf = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')

const handleStarSelect = (size) => {
    const children = form.children
    console.log(children[0])
    for (let i=0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if(i <= size) {
            children[i].classList.add('checked')
        } else {
            children[i].classList.remove('checked')
        }
    }
}

const handleSelect = (selection) => {
    switch(selection){
        case 'first':{
            handleStarSelect(1)
            return
        }
        case 'second':{
            handleStarSelect(2)
            return
        }
        case 'third':{
            handleStarSelect(3)
            return
        }
        case 'fourth':{
            handleStarSelect(4)
            return
        }
        case 'fifth':{
            handleStarSelect(5)
            return
        }
    }
}

const getNumericValue = (stringValue) =>{
    let numericValue;
    if (stringValue === 'first') {
        numericValue = 1
    } 
    else if (stringValue === 'second') {
        numericValue = 2
    }
    else if (stringValue === 'third') {
        numericValue = 3
    }
    else if (stringValue === 'fourth') {
        numericValue = 4
    }
    else if (stringValue === 'fifth') {
        numericValue = 5
    }
    else {
        numericValue = 0
    }
    return numericValue
}

if (one) {
    const arr = [one, two, three, four, five]

    arr.forEach(item=> item.addEventListener('mouseover', event=>{
        handleSelect(event.target.id)
    }))

    arr.forEach(item=> item.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
        const val = event.target.id
        console.log(val)

        form.addEventListener('submit', e=>{
            e.preventDefault()
            const id = e.target.id
            console.log(id)
            const val_num = getNumericValue(val)


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/rate/',
                data: {
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf[0].value,
                    'element_id': id,
                    'val': val_num,
                },
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response)
                    confirmBox.innerHTML = `<p>Successfully rated with ${response.score}</p>`
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error)
                    confirmBox.innerHTML = '<p>Oops... Something went wrong...</p>'
                }
            })
        })
    }))
}
```

And here is the error itself:

```
4
Internal Server Error: /rate/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Django/personal_blog/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/kali/Django/personal_blog/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/kali/Django/personal_blog/src/blog/views.py", line 91, in RateView
    obj = Rating.objects.get(id=element_id)
  File "/home/kali/Django/personal_blog/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kali/Django/personal_blog/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
blog.models.Rating.DoesNotExist: Rating matching query does not exist.
[29/Nov/2021 00:18:19] "POST /rate/ HTTP/1.1" 500 86956
```

As for me, the problem lies somewhere in the url. How to solve this problem?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwpod.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue doesn't lie in the url, but the query `obj = Rating.objects.get(id=element_id)`. There is no rating object with id=element_id.

To debug, check if the Rating id is passed correctly from RatingView -> Template -> JS -> RateView.

For example, obj might be empty in RatingView, to start with.

Comment: Even here `obj = Rating.objects.filter(score = 0).order_by("?").First()` is not correct. Can you tell me how I can associate a rating with a blog post? I need to send information on the post to `RatingView`